# IKImageView and scroll bars

Tags: objective-c, macos, interface-builder, ikimageview

I'm trying to use the IKImageViewDemo provided by apple (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/IKImageViewDemo/index.html) and I'm trying to add scrollbars to it. I've tried two things:

1) embedding the IKImageView in a ScrollView. This had all sorts of weird effects, like the image was no longer located where it should have been, and the scrollbars seemed to be in a fixed place, no matter how big the window was (So I could shrink the window and lose the scrollbars, even though the scrollview was set to resize with the window)

2) I added [_imageView setHasHorizontalScrollers: YES] (and vertical) into the code in the openImageURL method. This appears to have done nothing.

Am I missing something obvious?

Additionally: Why does

```
NSLog(@"scrollbar? H %d V %d hide %d", 
      _imageView.hasHorizontalScroller, 
      _imageView.hasVerticalScroller,
      _imageView.autohidesScrollers);

_imageView.hasHorizontalScroller = YES;
_imageView.hasVerticalScroller = YES;
_imageView.autohidesScrollers = YES;

NSLog(@"scrollbar? H %d V %d hide %d", 
      _imageView.hasHorizontalScroller, 
      _imageView.hasVerticalScroller,
      _imageView.autohidesScrollers);
```

give me:

```
scrollbar? H 0 V 0 hide 0
scrollbar? H 0 V 0 hide 0
```

?

Additionally additionally:

Equivalently why does:

```
 BOOL b = _imageView.autohidesScrollers = YES;
 NSLog (@"b %d scrollers %d", b, _imageView.autohidesScrollers);
```

print b 1 scrollers 0 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One thing that may have been catching you up in IKImageViewDemo was that the image was zoomed to fit in the `windowDidResize:` method (`[_imageView zoomImageToFit: self]`).

Embedding the IKImageView in a NSScrollView is the right thing to do.  In order to get the scrollbars to follow the window as you resize it, you need to adjust the springs and struts (== autoresizing mask) in Interface Builder.

**Addendum:** As you've noticed, there is a bug in Mac OS X 10.6 that causes this not to work properly.  You can work around the problem by subclassing the NSScrollView as follows:

```
@interface IKImageClipView : NSClipView
- (NSRect)docRect;
@end

@implementation ScrollViewWorkaround

- (void)reflectScrolledClipView:(NSClipView *)cView;
{
    NSView *_imageView = [self documentView];
    [super reflectScrolledClipView:cView];
    if ([_imageView isKindOfClass:[IKImageView class]] &&
         [[self contentView] isKindOfClass:[IKImageClipView class]] &&
         [[self contentView] respondsToSelector:@selector(docRect)]) {
        NSSize docSize = [(IKImageClipView *)[self contentView] docRect].size;
        NSSize scrollViewSize = [self contentSize];
        // NSLog(@"doc %@ scrollView %@", NSStringFromSize(docSize), NSStringFromSize(scrollViewSize));
        if (docSize.height > scrollViewSize.height || docSize.width > scrollViewSize.width)
         ((IKImageView *)_imageView).autohidesScrollers = NO;
        else
         ((IKImageView *)_imageView).autohidesScrollers = YES;
    }
}

@end
```

Try this out:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1583683/IKImageViewDemo.zip

It's a version of IKImageViewDemo with scroll bars and the above workaround.

Comment: thanks! I HAD disabled the window did resize thing... The problem with this (Which I've been having on my own version also) Is that when you make the window small enough that the image is bigger than the window in BOTH dimensions, the scrollbars dissapear. As long as the edge of the image is within the window (including scrollbars if present) in X or Y, then scrollbars appearn, but if you shrink it, they disappear! any thoughts on that?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Mac OS X 10.6 with IKImageView and autohiding scrollbars.  In 10.5 (where I was writing and testing it yesterday) both scroll bars do appear when you make the window smaller; but they both disappear on 10.6 once you get beyond the scroll bar's width (even with a binary built on 10.5).  On 10.6, my code does work if you set _imageView.autohidesScrollers = NO; though.  I'll see if I can figure out a workaround.

Comment: excellent thanks! I'm not sure how you got the IKImageView into the scrollview, but when I copied yours' and futzed with it a little I got it to work. thanks! (Now I just need to figure out how to lock the image to the top when resizing instead of the bottom... but that may boil down to just scrolling it while re-sizing...)

Comment: Click on the IKImageView in Interface Builder and choose Layout > Embed Objects In > Scroll View.  Glad you got it working!

Comment: but then how do you turn the scrollview into a scrollworkaround?

Comment: Ah, right. Click on the scroll view, click on the (i) tab in the inspector, then select from the Class menu under "Class Identity".

Comment: This appears to be broken in Mountain Lion.  I've opened a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231573/two-finger-drag-with-ikimageview-and-nsscrollview-in-mountain-lion.  if anyone has any thoughts on the issue, I'd very much like any feedback you might have.